# JavaScript RegExp evaluation

Tags: javascript, regex, evaluation

I was looking at some code and found the first line. I started to be confused when I discovered that if I try to make it simpler in such a way that the semantics remain the same, it is not the same and the result changes. Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

```
RegExp("\x3c").test(function(){return"\x3c"}) //false
RegExp("<").test(function(){return"<"})       //true
RegExp("\x3c").test("\x3c")                   //true
RegExp("<").test("<")                         //true
```

Comment: Don't know if you already know this, but you are not testing the return strings in first 2 lines. You would have to append `()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a non-string to `.test`, it gets converted to a string, *without* replacing any of the literal characters in the function's code. Look at the stringified version of your first two functions:

```js
console.log(function(){return"\x3c"}.toString());
console.log(function(){return"<"}.toString());
```

Because the source of the first function had `"\x3c"`, the stringified version includes that as well - the `"\x3c"` doesn't get replaced with `'<'`. Although `"\x3c" === '<'`, the interpreter doesn't make that replacement for you *when stringifying a function*.

When you pass `"\x3c"` to `new RegExp`, though (or to any function, such as with the third test), it *will* be turned into `'<'`:

```js
console.log("\x3c");
console.log(RegExp("\x3c"));
```

So, you original code is equivalent to:

```
/</.test(String.raw`function(){return"\x3c"}`); //false
/</.test(String.raw`function(){return"<"}`);    //true
/</.test("<");                        //true
/</.test("<");                        //true
```

Answer (score 0):

[test](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test) takes as param a string as default any other type will be converted to string

```js
const a = function(val) {
  return val
}
console.log(a)
const res = RegExp("\x3c").test(a) //false
const res2 = RegExp("<").test(a) //false

console.log(res, res2)

const b = function() {
  return "<"
}

const res3 = RegExp("<").test(b)

console.log(res3) //true
```

result `false` for both cause "function(val){return val}" does not contain any match

`res3` is true cause `"function(){return '<'}"` match `"<"`